# Why serverPrefetch effect is lost?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

Why second offer value in second `console.log` is null ?

```js
import {ref, onServerPrefetch, onMounted, inject} from 'vue';

const axios = inject('axios');
const route = inject('route');
const offer = ref(null);

const fetchOffer = async () => {
    try {
        const {data} = await axios(
            route('api.offer')
        );

        return data;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
    }
}

onServerPrefetch(async () => {
    offer.value = await fetchOffer();
    console.log('after fetch on server', offer.value) // offer is not null
});

onMounted(async () => {
    if (!offer.value) {
        console.log('fetch on mount', offer.value) // offer value is null! How?!
        offer.value = await fetchOffer();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's unknown how you observe that "offer is not null". onServerPrefetch and onMounted are mutually exclusive. The former is triggered on server side only, the latter is on client side only.

Comment: So if what you say is true, With every visit to my website, Two requests are sent to API !! That does not make sense.

Comment: It's not something I'm just saying, it's documented, https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html  . This is how SSR works. fetchOffer is supposed to be called on server and client side in different environments, this is at least 2 calls. `if (!offer.value) {` check is useless, there's no way how it could be not null in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for help. Javascript and it frameworks are trash.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent fetching data twice ?

Comment: Rethink the way you deal with data. If you've got data on server side, you can pass it to client side through global vars. e.g. `<script>window.myAppData = ...` and use it to hydrate a state, e.g. `if (window.myAppData?.foo) deepMerge(myFooState, window.myAppData.foo) else fetchFoo()` This makes the use of global store rather than local state much more preferable because you can handle hydration logic in one place. This is one of things that SSR frameworks like Nuxt can do for you. I don't use Inertia and cannot say if there are more specific solutions that are idiomatic to it.

Comment: This is good but i need better solution, sometimes passing data to DOM and hydrating it, makes HTML very huge.

Comment: That's why i want to use serverPrefetch for fetching data in my application, InertiaJS already pass all data to DOM and HTML gets 2MB larger that in actual size.

Comment: "already pass all data" - did you check how exactly data looks like in a payload? You shouldn't think of HTML and data as of a single thing, they are treated separately. It certainly won't be available on a client by magic like you tried with ref(). See https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#accessing-shared-data .

Comment: You miss understood what i said, InertiaJS adds all data coming from backing to HTML, Then after creating Vue instance in client, It reads all data from JSON data that wrote in HTML, This works pretty good but when i pass a large data to InertiaJS, HTML size gets really huge. I think what you mentioned in your previous comment was the same solution, But i'm migrating to another framework to solve large response size.

Comment: Look at my website, there is an attribute called data-page and all data that inertiaJS received is in data-page attribute. it's a really large and make some users with slow internet suffer from visiting my website.
http://mymember.shop/

Comment: Yes, that's the thing that's needed here. See the link with usePage, I'd expect that it's something like `const offer = ref(usePage().props.whatever || null)`. If data is guaranteed to exist on client side then you don't need to add `if (!offer.value) fetchOffer()`

Comment: Ok but is it possible to fetch data on server side not client side, And do not show data in HTML? I think there must be a trick or something

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you want to pass JSON data in data-app attribute like it's now, but not render the components on server side?

Comment: @EstusFlask This approach increases Content layout shift (CLS) in Lighthouse and it's really annoying. I've heard of server components in Nuxt which don't render on client side and only rendered version on server will be used on client side. How can i have this feature in VueJS + InertiaJS? Do you think i'm using the wrong approach to my issue? What should i do?

Comment: Makes sense then. This requires the explicit support from the framework, and I'm unaware of such for Inertia. I'd suggest to open an issue in its repo. Until then I'd stick to the approach above, `const offer = ref(usePage().props.whatever || null)`, possibly data could be filtered to contain only required fields to make it much less than 2mb.